# Created Jenkins pipeline and added the script in the Pipeline Description.To check out the Project from the svn repository.NotWorking. Any Suggestion

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'SubversionSCM',
                    additionalCredentials: [],
                    excludedCommitMessages: '',
                    excludedRegions: '',
                    excludedRevprop: '',
                    excludedUsers: '',
                    filterChangelog: false,
                    ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                    includedRegions: '',
                    locations: [[
                        cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true,
                        credentialsId: 'PTS-Cred', 
                        depthOption: 'infinity',
                        ignoreExternalsOption: true,
                        local: '.', 
                        remote: 'repo location'
                    ]],
                    quietOperation: true,
                    workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
                ])
            }
        }
    }
    
    post {
        success {
            echo 'Checkout successful'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Checkout failed'
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Jenkins log

```
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Help me to solve it.